# Adding multiple inline image spans

Tags: css

I have a few tutorials in the pipeline where I'd like to use arrow images (so up / down / left / right) to explain steps a user should take.

so screen result would look a bit as follows :

In order to proceed first select `[up_arrow_image]`, then click `[left_arrow_image]` twice, and select `[enter_image]`. There can be a few hundred of these steps in the end so I'd like to use inline spans to show the arrows, rather than coding them in the html directly. I've been able to get it running for the first span in my paragraph, but that's where it stopped.

my simplified html :

```
<p>In order to proceed first select <span class="arrow arrow_up"><!-- up --></span>,
then click <span class="arrow arrow_left"><!-- left --></span> twice, 
and select <span class="arrow select"><!-- up --></span></p>
```

and my css looks like this at the moment :

```
.arrow {
   display:inline_block;
   width: 20px; height: 20px;
   padding-left:20px;
   background-image: url(arrow.png);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.arrow_up {
     background-position: 0px 0px;
}

.arrow_left {
    background-position: 0px -20px;
}

.enter {
     background-position: 0px -40px;
}
```

I found most of above browsing here, but I overlooked something for sure as it's not really working out the way I hoped for. My first arrow shows up, but rest is neglected.

Comment: If you set the width to 20px and add a left-padding of 20px, the total width will be 40px.

Comment: I've noticed you've got no class name `select` in your css rules.  Did you mean for `.enter` in the CSS to be `.select`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the property is actually `inline-block` (not underscore), just change that and you should be in the clear

Comment: Man, I feel stupid now, aargh... Thanks for spotting it, it works fine now !